# How to use Linkedin API v2 from Javascript SDK?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'd like to use the v2 Linkedin API from the Javascript SDK. In the docs it says that to make an API call you use IN.API.Raw() but as default I see it is hitting the v1 API.

Docs also say that in order to use v2 you need to add X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0 in the headers. How can I add it by using the SDK so the calls are to the v2 of the API?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Andrés. Please consider the code you have already written for this. It would make both question and answer more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the V2 API you will need a partnership with linkedin
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

if you have this i would recommend using oauth.io SDK, they have great and easy guides available to make oauth happen for linkedin.